# Mounting existing SSD persistent disk to new instance (Google Cloud)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I don't know if it's because of limitation of SSD or something else, I can't see a partition on the disk to mount:

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-id/
google-dataserver2 -> ../../sda
google-dataserver2-part1 -> ../../sda1
google-ssd1 -> ../../sdb
scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_dataserver2 -> ../../sda
scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_dataserver2-part1 -> ../../sda1
scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_ssd1 -> ../../sdb
```

Since there is no **-part1** in the google-ssd1 disk, I can't mount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the filesystem starts at the begnining of the disk (instead of having a partition table at the start, and then the filesystem starting a few blocks later). Try mounting /dev/sdb or /dev/disk/by-id/google-ssd1 directly.

Comment: Didn't think of that until your answer :)